# Storing references in serializable classes (C# - XNA)

Tags: c#, serialization, reference, xna-4.0

I've been creating a game in XNA for the past couple weeks. In the process, I tried to solve a problem before I encountered it without fully understanding the problem.

That problem was how I was going to deal with saving and retrieving "blueprint" objects. I need this functionality due to a content creator that I'm making (the game is content-based). So the objective is, I create the content (rough example, an enemy of type "Goblin" with 100 health and a goblin sprite), save it to a serialized object, load it in the game, and then it is usable and duplicable in-game.

Now obviously when objects have something non-serializable like a Texture2D (the sprite), you can't serialize them. I solved that problem for both maps and objects with sprites (items, NPCs, characters, etc) by adding all my textures to a static class and only storing indices to the textures in the objects (e.g., instead of containing a Texture2D property, the Goblin would contain an index linking to the appropriate texture - slightly oversimplified but you get the idea).

But then the virus spread and I started doing that for all my object references. For example, the Goblin also needs a reference to an AI object. That AI object only has methods and as a result is clearly serializable, but I was storing it in the same static class as my textures and linking to it via index. Looking back on that now, I shudder as to what I was thinking.

So my question is, should everything except textures be stored by direct reference in serializable classes, instead of reference by index? Or is there ever a viable reason to do what I've done?

Serialization is a tricky business and I'm trying to wrap my head around the best ways to use it and the right times to avoid it.

Comment: Also, I'm not afraid to hear the cold hard truth (that I've made a terrible mistake). My static class is still handy as a means of loading and saving objects for my content creation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, serialization cannot keep track of references. Either you serialize the whole object graph, or you come up with your own way of resolving references upon deserializing. So what you did was the right thing to do, although you might want to find a better solution instead of just hanging everything from a static class.

Also, you might want to change your strategy. Instead of saving the object itself with all the indices, you could save only the required information, and then have a resolver factory that would read this info and populate an object with the right values.

Comment: What would be the problem with serializing all the objects? And what would be a better solution?

Comment: +1. I'd note that "references" in serialization context should not be confused with "references vs. value types" as C#/CLR concept. See if "owns/contains" (i.e. goblin contains max health counter) and "refers to" (i.e. goblin refers to some create AI and texture) sounds better...

Comment: I can think of two problems: 1) you will serialize copies of everything. For example, any shared texture your models use, will get saved each time you save a model. Also, upon deserialization, each instance will have its own copy of the textute (thus defeating the purpose of having shared textures in the first place) 2) you might end up serializing more than you want. While it is possible to specify which fields you want to serialize, it might happen that a seemingly innocent looking reference might pull a huge number of associated objects with it.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Makes perfect sense now (I wasn't aware of the duplicate copy problem).

Comment: @Djentleman, it is your project - we don't know why serializing all objects would be a problem for you. But whatever you do decide to do make sure to correctly serialize shared objects that are referenced by multiple objects (i.e. "sword" can be referenced by half of your creatues, but still likely need to be single shared instance in serialized data) and see if you need to deal with cycles (unlikely as you'd hit it by now).

Comment: Just want to add an extra thank you to this. After a bit more research I think I have a much fuller understanding of the iffy realm of serialization. I'll be sticking to my static class approach for the time being (just want to get a working prototype for now) and refactoring if I feel performance or space are issues. I'll probably end up posting another question on the topic when I get to the that point. Thanks again!